# Multiple Listviews IDs confusion

Tags: asp.net

`enter code here`I am building user controls to display items in listviews with pagers. If I have only one usercontrol (SharePoint 2010 webpart), it is perfectly working with the following code :

ASCX :

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="table">
                <tr id="tableRow">
                    <td id="column1" class="tableCell">
                        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <div class="pager">
        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" PagedControlID="ListView" runat="server">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="False" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                    ShowPreviousPageButton="true" PreviousPageText="<" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="True" />
                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"
                    ShowNextPageButton="true" NextPageText=">" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager
</div>
```

Code behind :

```
                DataPager.PageSize = X;
                ListView.DataSource = items.ToList();
                ListView.DataBind();
```

The problem is when I put two of these ascx on my page, all the items are going to the first listview : of course because they don't have a different ID. But how could I give them a different ID as I cannot know, in advance, how many user controls I will have ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the client id mode of your user control and the child controls inside that control........

use this

```
 ClientIDMode="AutoID"
```